# Hide editor-label for public property when calling EditorFor(...)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor, editorformodel, meta-attribute

When calling `Html.EditorFor(m => m)`, where `m` is a public class with public properties,  a hidden input **and a label** are displayed for properties with the **`[HiddenInput]`** attribute.

- How can I hide the label without making it private or creating an editor template?

## Example

```
public class User
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } // should not be displayed in editor template
    public string Name { get; set; } // should be editable
}
```

### Undesired result for ID property by `EditorFor(...)` *with* label

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="ID">ID</label> <!-- Why is this here? -->
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`, which hides the input as well, but I want to keep the hidden input and just get rid of the label.

Comment: Tried `[DisplayName("")]`, which hides the `<label>` tag, but not the surrounding `<div class="editor-label">` with "*" required indicator inside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solved with:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
```

Otherwise `HideSurroundingHtml` is not set correctly.