# MVC 3 Editor Templates don't seem to respect HiddenInput

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

Following Brad Wilson's excellent series on [using and customizing editor templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html), I tried adding an Object.cshtml to the `Shared\EditorTemplates` folder. The template renders, but the `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` on a model property doesn't render a hidden `<input type="hidden" ... />` as expected. Using `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]` renders both the hidden and visible elements as expected.

I have verified that the default template for `Object` works fine and renders the hidden inputs. It's only a problem when building a custom template based on Brad's series above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide editor-label for public property when calling EditorFor(...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793545/hide-editor-label-for-public-property-when-calling-editorfor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something has changed. Inspecting the MVC 3 source, I found that `prop.HideSurroundingHtml` is used to determine when to print the surrounding HTML, not to print only the hidden element. The following template allows several levels of rendering an editor for an object graph:

```
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 2)
{
    @(ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model != null ?
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText :
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText)
}
else
{
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
    {
        if (!prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString()))
            {
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)</div>
            }
            @Html.Raw("<div class=\"editor-field\">")
        }
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
        if (!prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
            @Html.Raw("</div>")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tidied my version of that up a bit for anyone who cares:

```
@foreach (var modelMetadata in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (modelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml == false)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(modelMetadata.PropertyName).ToHtmlString()))
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label(modelMetadata.PropertyName)
            </div>
        }

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor(modelMetadata.PropertyName)
        </div>
    }
}
```